# Can I treat a reference type as a value type here, or do I need to clone?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, value-type, reference-type

Consider the following method:

```
public (MySpecialType one, MySpecialType two) ReturnTwoSeparateObjects()
{
   MySpecialType before = new MySpecialType();
   MySpecialType after = before;
   after.MyProperty = "A value";
   return (before, after); // These will be the same object, pointless returning twice
}
```

This will return the same object, since the assignment of `after` is simply the same reference to the memory allocated for `before`. I understand that, but I want to return a representation of the object before and after a property was changed.

I know I can probably deep clone `before` using serialization or something, but it seems like a pretty heavy approach (I may be wrong on this, it's an assumption). Assuming I wanted to avoid a deep clone, is there some way to treat `before` as a value type here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you don't need to use serialization, but you *do* need to create separate objects. Quite how deeply you need to clone will depend on the type - for example, you don't need to clone any immutable types. (The more immutability you can introduce into your code, the easier this becomes.)

There's no concept of "treating a reference type as a value type", but even if there were it would only naturally perform a *shallow* clone anyway, so you wouldn't be much better off.

Comment: Thanks Jon. It's prompted a dig into various types of cloning and with these members being immutable I think one of the approaches you might be referring to is memberwise clone, I think that does what I need it to. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

With the advent of [C# 9](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/c-9-0-on-the-record/) you have the option to define the `MySpecialType` as `record` instead of `class`, and do this:

```
public (MySpecialType one, MySpecialType two) ReturnTwoSeparateObjects()
{
    var before = new MySpecialType();
    var after = before with { MyProperty = "A value" };
    return (before, after);
}
```

The method will return two different references, representing different versions of the same entity.

The records are immutable by default, and they are intended to be used as such.